# Как правильно собрать статистику по DataFrame'у

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, csv, dataframe

У меня есть рабочий и корректный код, который подсчитывает кол-во значений заданных в файле в виде массива.

Возможно ли отказаться от использования двух циклов в коде и заменить их на функции pandas?

```
import pandas as pd 
import argparse as ap


def ArgParser():
    parser = ap.ArgumentParser(description='Description of your program')
    parser.add_argument('-d','--data', help='Test result', required=True)
    args = vars(parser.parse_args())
    return args

def main():

    args = ArgParser()
    csv = pd.read_csv(args['data'], sep=';', header=0)
    df = pd.DataFrame(csv)

    dl = []
    for index, row in df.iterrows():
        for id in range(1, len(row.values)):
            dl.append(row.values[id])

    ds = pd.Series(dl)  
    vdc = ds.value_counts()
    print(vdc)


if __name__ == '__main__':

    main()
```

Входные данные:

```
c1;c2;c3;c4;c5;c6;c7;c8
1;9;11;17;29;30;33;36
2;5;6;9;11;15;33;28
3;4;5;10;14;20;30;8
```

На выходе (пример данных):

```
30    2
11    2
36    2
5     2
6     2
4     2
9     2
33    2
17    1
15    1
29    1
20    1
10    1
21    1
8     1
22    1
25    1
26    1
28    1
14    1
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно все сделать одной командой:

```
In [61]: (pd.read_csv(r'D:\download\data.csv', sep=';')
            .stack()
            .value_counts())
Out[61]:
5     2
33    2
11    2
30    2
9     2
14    1
4     1
2     1
3     1
36    1
6     1
10    1
8     1
15    1
17    1
20    1
28    1
29    1
1     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Просто и красиво!

Comment: @YuriyTigiev, согласен :-D